# Sql developer ORA-29531

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Trying to make Java function work from member function. I am new to this so i don't know where the mistake might be. Will copy all the relevant code.

```
create or replace
type sfera as object(
radius number(10,2),
member function tilpums(radius double precision) return double precision);

create or replace and compile JAVA source named "Papild" as 
public class Papild {
public static double rek(double radius)
{
return 3.14*radius*radius*radius*4/3;
}   
}

create or replace
type body sfera as
member function tilpums(radius double precision) return double precision as Language java 
Name 'Papild.rek(double) return double';
end;

Create table sferas of sfera;

Insert into sferas values(4);

select value(a).tilpums(radius) from sferas a;
```

and from the select i get the following error message:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
select value(a).tilpums(radius) from sferas a
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-29531: no method rek in class Papild
29531. 00000 -  "no method %s in class %s"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to execute a non-existent method in a
           Java class.
*Action:   Adjust the call or create the specified method.
```

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can suggest just a workaround (not a prefect by working one) - use standalong function and call it in member one:

```
SQL> create or replace function standalon_tilpums(radius double precision)
  2  return double precision as Language java
  3  Name 'Papild.rek(double) return double';
  4  /

SQL> select standalon_tilpums(4) from dual;

STANDALON_TILPUMS(4)                                                            
--------------------                                                            
          267,946667                                                            

SQL> create or replace
  2  type sfera as object(
  3  radius number(10,2),
  4  member function tilpums(radius double precision) return double precision);
  5  /

SQL> create or replace
  2  type body sfera as
  3  member function tilpums(radius double precision) return double precision
  4  is begin return standalon_tilpums(radius); end;
  5  end;
  6  /

SQL> Create table sferas of sfera;

SQL> Insert into sferas values(4);

SQL> select value(a).tilpums(radius) from sferas a;

VALUE(A).TILPUMS(RADIUS)                                                        
------------------------                                                        
              267,946667
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. This is an extra assignment for me and i don't clearly know the rules i have to follow.

Comment: The solution was accepted but i still want to know how to do this without this workaround.